# how to add two time more than 24 hours

Tags: php, time

I have to write a php function for adding 2 time variables which in more than 24 hours.
**time function**

```
    function TimeSum($a,$b)
  {
    list ($hour1, $min1, $sec1) = explode(':', $a);
    list ($hour2, $min2, $sec2) = explode(':', $b);

      $sumHour = sprintf('%02d', $hour1 + $hour2);
      $sumMin = sprintf('%02d', $min1 + $min2);
      $sumSec = sprintf('%02d', $sec1 + $sec2);

   return $sumHour.':'.$sumMin.':'.$sumSec;
  }
```

but the problem is the sum of `$a=50:15:00` and `$b=22:55:00` show the result as `72:70:00` not `73:10:00`  .how do i fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using PHP's DateTime and DateInterval classes?

Comment: according to the my requirement can't use as  DateTime

Comment: Why not?  It seems strange that a requirement cares about how you might get to an answer, and the DateTime classes have been standard in PHP for years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical error in your code, you just simply sum every part of the time but the thing you need to do is this :

If number of seconds is superior to 60 you have to get only the result of $number_seconds%60 and add it to your minutes and repeat it with the minutes, let me show you :

```
       function TimeSum($a,$b)
          {
            list ($hour1, $min1, $sec1) = explode(':', $a);
            list ($hour2, $min2, $sec2) = explode(':', $b);
//counting number of seconds and getting extra minutes outs
            $total_sec = $sec1+$sec2;
            $sumSec = $total_sec%60;
            $extra_min = ($total_sec-$sumSec)/60;
//counting number of minutes and getting extra hours outs
            $total_min= $min1+$min2+$extra_min;
            $sumMin = $total_min%60;
            $extra_hr = ($total_min-$sumMin)/60;
//counting number of hours
            $sumHour = $hour1 + $hour2 + $extra_hr;

            return $sumHour.':'.$sumMin.':'.$sumSec;
          }
```

Comment: you are correct.i got the result like 59:0:0 .can you result format as 59:00:00 like this

Comment: Just do something like ` $sumSec < 9 ? echo '0'.$sumSec : echo $sumSec ` or output however you like, you are not obliged to return the data as it is, manipulate it before you output it

Comment: can't i return value as 59:00:00?

Comment: We're dealing with variables here, an int variable is 0, 1 , 2 ... so if you want the result to show like that you have to change how your variables will look, just concatenate it with 0 if it's less than 9 (check the solution that I gave you for example)

Comment: bro i find the way to do it .any way thank you very much for valuable attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime to work with minutes and seconds as a unix timestamp, and calculate hours only. I'm sure there is a better/prettier solution, but this one works out of the box:

```
function TimeSum( $a, $b ) {

  list ( $hourA, $minA, $secA ) = explode( ':', $a );
  list ( $hourB, $minB, $secB ) = explode( ':', $b );

  $timeStamp = strtotime( '1970-01-01 00:' . $minA . ':' . $secA );
  $timeStamp += strtotime( '1970-01-01 00:' . $minB . ':' . $secB );

  $minutesAndSeconds = date( ':i:s', $timeStamp );
  $hours = date( 'H', $timeStamp );

  return sprintf( '%02d', $hours + $hourA + $hourB ) . $minutesAndSeconds;

}
```